# How to get response url from HINTERNET

Tags: c++, wininet

when i access URL like this: http://www.misslee.net/_common/inc/mi3dark_down.asp 
it returns me to the real URL => http://125.141.146.184:8080/download/SetupMisslee_Dark.exe

I guess I was redirected.. I want to know the redirected URL. Please help me.
How to get response url from HINTERNET?

```
 TCHAR szServerName[] = _T("www.misslee.net");  
 TCHAR szFormAction[] = _T("/_common/inc/mi3dark_down.asp");
 TCHAR szHeader[500] = {0,};
 LPCWSTR accept[2]={_T("*/*"), NULL};

 DWORD_PTR dwContext=1;
 BOOL  bResult;
 DWORD  dwSize;

 HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpen( _T("HTTP-POST"), INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0 );

 HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnect( hInternet, szServerName, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT, NULL, _T("HTTP/1.1"), INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, dwContext);

 HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequest( hConnect, _T("POST"), szFormAction, _T("HTTP/1.1"), NULL, accept,INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE, dwContext);

 bResult = HttpSendRequest( hRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);

// Redirected response url???????????
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `InternetQueryOption` with [`INTERNET_OPTION_URL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385328#INTERNET_OPTION_URL) flag.

> INTERNET_OPTION_URL
>
> Retrieves a string value that **contains the full URL** of a downloaded resource. If the original URL contained any extra data,
>   such as search strings or anchors, **or if the call was redirected, the
>   URL returned differs from the original**. This option is valid on
>   HINTERNET handles returned by InternetOpenUrl, FtpOpenFile,
>   GopherOpenFile, or HttpOpenRequest. It is used by InternetQueryOption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`HttpQueryInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384238%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function with the [`HTTP_QUERY_LOCATION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385351%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) query information flag to get the response location.

From MSDN:

> **HTTP_QUERY_LOCATION**
>
> > 33
> >     Retrieves the absolute Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) used in a Location response-header.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing automatic WinInet redirect handling, where API receives redirection response and automatically re-sends another request to return redirected request data to the caller, thus handling redirects transparently.

If you are not happy with this, provide your request with [`INTERNET_FLAG_NO_AUTO_REDIRECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa452096.aspx) flag and disable redirections. You will receive the original response, query for headers and decide whether you want to issue second request or not.

> Does not automatically handle redirection. This flag can also be used
>   by InternetOpenUrl for HTTP requests.